# HTML TextArea Break Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my site im inserting long length text without space  in text area and view then view that text inside `<p>` or `<div>` tag.but text dosn't break it shows as inline.how can i view text with proper spacing.

This is code for view textarea

```css
.text_in_status p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
    

}
```

```html
<div className="text_in_status clearfix">
                <p >{this.props.post.text}</p>
              </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use "word-break: break-all;" style for p tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.text_in_status p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
</style>
<div className="text_in_status clearfix">
    <p >{this.props.post.text}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one in p tag:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `word-break: break-all;` this style on your p tag.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text_in_status p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
   word-wrap:break-word;
    

}
```

```html
<div className="text_in_status clearfix">
                <p >{this.props.post.textsdsfsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd    dfsfffffffffffffffffffffffffff ddddddddddddddddd}</p>
              </div>
```